# Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'student_id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, php-codebrowser

I'm receiving the following error code when trying to "Add a New Student" to MySQL database scheduler program:

Invalid query:

```
INSERT INTO student(student_id, name, password, number_paid_lessons, paid_from_date, paid_until_date) VALUES('DEFAULT', 'Test Student', 'Test Password', 12, '2014-1-01', '2014-3-31')
```

> Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'student_id' at row 1

The tech staff at my hosting company explained:
"Means that the incorrect mysql value is DEFAULT into row student_id."

Coding is in php...How to fix?
Do I just need to change the insert.php page code...or...the student.php page code? If so, to what?

Comment: Hummm...I don't see 'DEFAULT' in any of my code.

Comment: Below is the code on the addStudent.php page which creates a new student:

Comment: <?php
require_once('classes/Student.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
header("Location: login.html");
exit;
}
$name      = $_POST['name'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$startYear = $_POST['startYear'];
$startMonth = $_POST['startMonth'];
$endYear   = $_POST['endYear'];
$endMonth  = $_POST['endMonth'];
$numberOfLessons = $_POST['numberOfLessons'];
$lastDay   = date('t', mktime(0,0,0,$endMonth, 1, $endYear));
Student::create($name, $password, $numberOfLessons, "$startYear-$startMonth-01", "$endYear-$endMonth-$lastDay");
header("Location: studentAdmin.php");
exit;
?>

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass `'DEFAULT'`. Just leave that column out of your column list and values list, and the default will get inserted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `student_id` column has a set default value you do not need to specify it in your query for the default value to be applied.

```
INSERT INTO student(name, password, number_paid_lessons, paid_from_date, paid_until_date) 
VALUES('Test Student', 'Test Password', 12, '2014-1-01', '2014-3-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

If student_id is an autoincrement field, just leave it empty

```
INSERT INTO student(student_id, name, password, number_paid_lessons, paid_from_date, paid_until_date) 
VALUES('', 'Test Student', 'Test Password', 12, '2014-1-01', '2014-3-31')
```

Else, give a number instead of default

```
INSERT INTO student(student_id, name, password, number_paid_lessons, paid_from_date, paid_until_date) 
VALUES(1, 'Test Student', 'Test Password', 12, '2014-1-01', '2014-3-31')
```